# D3.js force layout implementing scrollable zoom

Tags: d3.js, zooming, force-layout

I have been trying to implment zooming to my d3 froce layout diagram. I am aware of the on mouse wheel function, but thus far, all my attempts have resulted in the diagram appearing at maximum zoom and be completely non-responsive to the mouse wheel. I am new to d3, and thus far all my attempts at debugging the code have proven fruitless. Can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 800,
    height = 800;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(5)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
  .attr({
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "100%"
    })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
  .attr("pointer-events", "all")
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

var vis = svg
    .append('svg:g');

function redraw() {
    vis.attr("transform",
  "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
  + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
console.log(graph);
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart)
    .on("drag", dragmove)
    .on("dragend", dragend);

function zoom() {
svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function dragstart(d, i) {
    force.stop() // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
    d.fixed = true;
}

function dragmove(d, i) {
    d.px += d3.event.dx;
    d.py += d3.event.dy;
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy; 
    tick(); // this is the key to make it work together with updating both px,py,x,y on d !
}

function dragend(d, i) {
    d.fixed = true; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
    tick();
    force.resume();
}

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .append("text")
              .attr("class", "nodetext")
              .attr("dx", 12)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name });
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .select("text")
            .remove()
        });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043)?

Comment: I have. It is what i used to implement my current zooming system, and it ended up with the system that I currently have, stuck at max zoom and unresponsive to mouse scrolls. If you have any other examples, or an idea of what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate your input.